# Error: Conflicting types in structs pointers

Tags: c, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to convert a fixed struct into dynamic struct but I get next errors: `warning: data definition has no type or storage class` and `warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'clientes' [-Wimplicit-int]`. I will show my project:

FILE `variablesPrototypes.h`

```
struct viaje {
    char identificador[MAX_TAM_IDENTIFICADOR+3];
    char ciudadDestino[MAX_TAM_CIUDAD_DESTINO+3];
    char hotel[MAX_TAM_HOTEL+3];
    int numeroNoches;
    char tipoTransporte[MAX_TAM_TIPO_TRANSPORTE+3];
    float precioAlojamiento;
    float precioDesplazamiento;
};

struct cliente {
    char dni[MAX_TAM_DNI+3];
    char nombre[MAX_TAM_NOMBRE+3];
    char apellidos[MAX_TAM_APELLIDOS+3];
    char direccion[MAX_TAM_DIRECCION+3];
    int totalViajes;
    struct viaje viajes[MAX_TAM_VIAJES_CLIENTE];
};

extern struct cliente *clientes;
```

FILE `applicationVariables.c`

```
clientes = (struct cliente *)malloc(sizeof(struct cliente)*1);
```

In my `main.c` first include `variablesPrototypes.h` and then `applicationVariables.c`.

Why could it be? I have been testing a lot of things for a long time but I did not solve the problem. Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Why is your `main.c` including another C file? You should only include header files

Comment: Yes, I know, It is an different file folder I am doing. All my .c is not autolinked nor autocompiled if I do not include them

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to use Makefiles. And you should expand your question with a [mcve] as it's currently lacking enough information

Comment: Your header contains some declaration. But there is no definition of `clientes`. Also we cannot see if your assignment is on file scope or function scope. Please provide a MCVE.

Comment: how can i do a MCVE of c? JSLint only let do it in JavaScript

Comment: Your question is about a C program, so why do you through in JavaScript here??

Comment: I say that I know how to do a MCVE of Javascript with JSLint, but I do not know which page use for create a MCVE of C

Comment: MCVE means minimum, complete, verifyable example. Take your program with the problem, strip down everything not required to show the problem. Keep **everything** required to compile. => MCVE. There is no relation to any "pages" or JavaScript of JSLint or whatever.

Comment: Then, my code is a MCVE. Have all necesary for work. Only is needed include the files in main.c

Comment: @JuMoGar So in other words, its not.  An MCVE is one or more complete source files along with compiler commands that others can run that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @JuMoGar No, your code is not a [MCVE]. It is minimal, but not complete.

Comment: oh, ok, thank you then. For next time, I'll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Put `struct cliente *` in front of `clientes` in `applicationVariables.c`. You have declared `clientes`, but you have not **defined it**, so, currently, you have not allocated space for `clientes` and you cannot assign it.
2. As is now, `clientes` would be **defined** at global scope, out of any runtime context, so you can not use a *run-time function* like `malloc` to initialize it. Either you just define it with a constant initializer or you move it inside `main()` or any other function.

Comment: Then, you have another error, but your current error is this one. Also, put the definition of `clientes` inside a function... It seems you would be assigning a non-const value to a global scope variable

Comment: I added some comments here to make it complete.

Comment: I have already tryed both things:

- Point 1: Already done that, I get this error: `error: initializer element is not constant`.

- Point 2: So... I can not initialize this var (*clientes) on the scope? obligatory must be inside a function?.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: well, to make a function run before `main` you can declare it as a *constructor*. In C there are not explicit constructor, however gcc provides [`__attribute__((constructor))`](https://phoxis.org/2011/04/27/c-language-constructors-and-destructors-with-gcc/) which you could use with the same end result